# Trying to get property of non-object using stdClass Object

Tags: php

I have a foreach

```
foreach ($records as $record) {
    print_r($record);
}
```

that is returning:

> stdClass Object (
>       [business_unit] => FHUSA
>       [location_id] => ATLANTA )

How would I call those two properties in my foreach?

I've tried doing: `$test = strtoupper(str_replace(' ', '', trim($records->location_id) . trim($records->business_unit)));` and I'm getting a `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object` error.

I want the variable $test to store the output of each location_id and business_unit

Comment: $record is an object, - the data is an array, use array notary

Comment: In your loop - you would need to reference the individual object - `trim($record->location_id)` (i.e. `$record` not `$records`)

Comment: @NigelRen, that was the case - I so overlooked that smh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop - you would need to reference the individual object -

```
foreach ($records as $record) {
    $test = strtoupper(str_replace(' ', '', trim($record->location_id) . 
           trim($record->business_unit)));
}
```

(i.e. `$record` not `$records`)

You should either add to `$test` using `.=` in the loop or add it to an array if you need all of the data from multiple records...

```
$test = []
foreach ($records as $record) {
    $test[] = strtoupper(str_replace(' ', '', trim($record->location_id) . 
           trim($record->business_unit)));
}
```

Comment: So since if I `print_r($test)` will only return one result from $result, how would I be able to return the results from all the $records?